# Is there an annotation to ignore mapping a specific abstract method that will be overridden in a child class?

Tags: mapstruct

I'm looking to use mapstruct on many methods in a hierarchy of classes, but I need some of the abstract methods at higher levels not be automatically mapped by mapstruct, as they will have full implementations in child classes. Is there an annotation for this that I missed in the mapstruct documentation?

```java
//I did not place @Mapper here because there are no methods to create maps for in this class
public abstract class SuperParentMapper {

  //declaration I want mapstruct to ignore
  public abstract Hoopdy hangdyToHoopdy(Hangdy hangdy);

}

@Mapper(componentModel = "cdi")
public abstract class NextParentMapper extends SuperParentMapper {

  //declaration I also want mapstruct to ignore
  @Override
  public abstract Hoopdy hangdyToHoopdy(Hangdy hangdy);

  //There are some other methods in here that I do need mapstruct to implement

}

@Mapper(componentModel = "cdi")
public abstract class DatChildMapper extends NextParentMapper {

  @Override
  public Hoopdy hangdyToHoopdy(Hangdy hangdy){
    //actual implementation
  }

  //There are some other methods in here that I do need mapstruct to implement

}
```

I want the child class(es) to be the actual implementation, but it seems like mapstruct is trying to automatically create code for these parent classes. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I can't seem to get it to just use the child implementation. Before it's mentioned, I do need these parent classes to have the abstract methods so that I can hand around the parents and access these methods from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that might make the same mistake I did, don't put the @Mapper on the middle level parent class. That was the issue. It generated just fine when I took that out.